# How can I know what programs some apt-get package contains?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I would like to know what some specific **package** installs, for example, when installing `ncurses`, I have found that <kbd>TAB</kbd> key expands:

```
sudo apt-get install ncurses-
```

to show:

```
ncurses-base      ncurses-doc       ncurses-hexedit
ncurses-bin       ncurses-examples  ncurses-term
```

How could I know what, say, `ncurses-term` installs? I am interested mainly in programs, but libraries and any other filetypes could be useful too.

**Command-line** method, if possible, would be preferred (*any others* accepted too).

Comment: When you say "programs" are you talking about binaries?

Comment: Binaries and scripts, if possible, thanks, @Braiam.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are a few options, these will list *all* the files installed by a package:

#### A. Listing all files included in a package

1. **For installed packages**

   ```
    dpkg -L ncurses-term
   ```
2. **For all packages, installed or not**

   ```
    apt-file -F list ncurses-term
   ```

The `-F` turns of pattern matching so that only packages whose *exact* name matches are returned. You may need to install `apt-file` with `sudo apt-get install apt-file` and then update its database with `sudo apt-file update`.

#### B. Listing only executable files included in a package

1. **For installed packages**

Just install `dlocate` (`sudo apt-get install dlocate`) and run:

```
    dlocate -lsbin ncurses-term
```

As explained in `man dlocate`:

> -lsbin List  full  path/filenames of executable files (if any) in package

If you don't want to install additional packages, you can do this manually. Just collect the list of files and find any among them that have the executable bit set:

```
    apt-file -F list ncurses-term | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | 
        while read file; do [[ -x $file && -f $file ]] && echo "$file"; done
```

The little scriptlet above will print the path only (`cut -d ' ' -f 2`) and then pass it through a `while` loop that checks if the file is executable (`-x $file`) and if it is a regular file, no directories or symlinks (`-f $file`) and prints its name only if passes both tests.

2. **For all packages, installed or not**

There is no way I know of to list only executables included in an uninstalled package. However, since most executables are installed to `bin` directories, you can get most of them by parsing the output:

```
     apt-file -F list ncurses-term | grep -Ew "bin|sbin"
```

The `-w` option matches entire words, so you don't get things installed in, for example, `trashbin` or whatever.

---

**NOTE**: None of the above commands will produce any output for `ncurses-term` but that is because this package installs no executable files. The commands work nevertheless, try with a different package.

Comment: Hi terdon, are you sure the command should work on not-installed applications? when I try, it simply offers to install. Which is not that strange, as the .install file is (probably) downloaded with the application?

Comment: @Jacob yes, I just tried with a package I know is not installed and   `apt-file` listed the package's contents. Works on Debian testing and Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Aha, thanks, it makes sence I just thought, as the dependecies are shown as well on not installed applications.

Answer (score 5):

You could use apt-file:

```
sudo apt-file update        
apt-file list package_name
```

Comment: If `apt-file` is not installed you can install it with `sudo apt-get install apt-file`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a possibility using your browser (therefore not requiring access to a APT-system). For example, to list the file contents of package "ncurses-term", just type

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/ncurses-term/filelist

into your browser's address bar (replace "wheezy" as needed) for Debian or

http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/all/ncurses-term/filelist

for Ubuntu (replace "saucy" as needed).

Comment: An interesting method. This list is for Debian packages, so: is it supposed to be the same for any other distro like Ubuntu or Kali?

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez: Read precisely: I have also posted the link for the same package (ncurses-term in this example) for Ubuntu. The file list _might_ be the same if a specific Ubuntu version has the same version of the package than one of the Debian sets, but it isn't necessarily. Ubuntu, Kali, Aptosid, CrunchBang and all the other Debian-based distributions could make modifications to packages as they like (especially files like "README" or configuration files for the init system).

Comment: I understand, @MichaelKremser. So, as I can see, searching the web for the contents of a package is useful but, preferably, you should search on the official package list of your specific distro.

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez: Yes, right. If you're on Debian Wheezy, use the package list for Debian Wheezy, if you're on Debian testing, use that one, if you're on Ubuntu Precise, take its list. There always can be differences, although for example Ubuntu takes a lot of packages from Debian unmodified. However, this might change anytime.