# How do I list commands a package provides?

Tags: package-management, executable

I'm curious what commands a certain package provides my system with. By command, I mean an in-path executable that I can run from the command line (`ls`, `grep`, `sed`, etc).

I'm ***not*** trying to work out the package from the command, which can be done with:

```
dpkg -S `which command`
```

I want the opposite, a list of commands from a package.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176679/how-to-find-the-executable-file-of-an-app-if-whereis-is-not-showing-it This seems like related question.

Comment: Perhaps this could be merged with [How can I know what programs does some apt-get package contents?](http://askubuntu.com/q/435168)? It has pretty much the same information, only the answers don't limit themselves to the PATH. Merging might be a good idea to have the PATH approach as well.

Answer (score 8):

The following little loop will handle this *with installed packages*.

```
$ for f in $(dpkg -L login); do [[ $(type -P "${f##*/}") == "$f" ]] && echo ${f##*/}; done
nologin
lastlog
newgrp
faillog
su
login
sg
```

How it works:

- `dpkg -L package` generates a list of *all* the files in a package which we iterate through.
- We strip off the directory name with a little bashism: `${f##*/}` and
- Using the bash-builtin `type -P command` we see if that command is both in the path and that its path equals the file we started with.
- We finish by pumping out the shortened command.
- `[[ condition ]] && command` is just a bash shorthand for an if..then statement.

It's important to note that not all packages contain the commands you would expect them to. Apache is split out over multiple packages (with `-common` and `-bin` subpackages) and the `vlc` command isn't in the `vlc` package, it's in `vlc-nox`. There are *many* examples like that.

---

This can be adapted per [Gilles's idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/436332/449), doing a string match instead of actually checking, but keeping it all in one bash process (and still using the *whole* path).

```
for f in $(dpkg -L login); do [[ $f =~ ^${PATH//:/|} ]] && echo ${f##*/}; done
```

The major difference here is the `[[$f =~ ^${PATH//:/|} ]]`. That's an in-Bash regex search. The `${PATH//:/|}` part is taking the contents of $PATH and is hacking them into a dirty little regex. The condition should check the string begins with part of the path.

Comment: I tried `for f in $(dpkg -L apache2); do [[ $(type -P "${f##*/}") == "$f" ]] && echo ${f##*/}; done`  NO results

Comment: @user259474 This is expected. The `apache2` package doesn't contain much, it's more a of a meta package. The commands are in `-common` and `-bin` subpackages.

Comment: That's a bizarre way of doing it: more complex and less reliable than looking for `/bin` and friends textually.

Answer (score 4):

List the files in the package which are in a directory in the PATH. You only have to consider the default PATH, not any user customizations, since packages only use standard directories.

```
dpkg -L PACKAGE-NAME… | sed -n 's!^\(/s\?bin\|/usr/s\?bin\|/usr/games\)/!!p' | sort
```

Remove the `s\?` parts if you only want the programs intended for ordinary users without `sudo`.

If the package isn't installed, replace `dpkg -L` by [`apt-file -F list`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptFile).

This misses a few programs because they are provided via [alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). For example, for the [`ftp`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ftp) package, only `netkit-ftp` and `pftp` are provided, but this package actually provides the `ftp` command, because `/usr/bin/ftp` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/ftp` which is a symbolic link to one of the `ftp` implementations on the system, potentially `/usr/bin/netkit-ftp`. The following command (which isn't an example of good programming, just a big one-liner) lists the commands provided by a package via the alternatives mechanism, as currently configured.

```
perl -lwe 'foreach (`dpkg -L @ARGV`) {chomp; ++$p{$_}} foreach (</bin/* /sbin/* /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/*>) {$e = readlink; next unless defined $e and $e =~ m!^/etc/alternatives/!; $t = readlink $e; print if $p{$t}}' PACKAGE_NAME…
```

If you want to list the commands that could be provided via an alternative which is currently configured to point to a different package, you need to parse the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`.

Symbolic links and configuration files that implement the alternatives mechanisms are not registered in packages but registered automatically in `postinst`, which makes it difficult (and in fact technically impossible if a package's installation script doesn't follow conventions) to query the alternatives provided by an uninstalled package.

Comment: I'm a bit wary of `apt-file` mostly because it entails downloading a large amount of data before you can start using it. For a lot of packages, some sort of spin around `apt-get download` would be faster.

Comment: @Oli I wish that `apt-file` was part of the default installation. The amount of data is only a little more than one non-incremental round of `apt-get update`, and it's something you need to do once per release.

Comment: `lightdm` appears to the only path in $PATH that buck's the trend here. You're not catching `/usr/lib/lightdm/` which contains executables for some ungodly reason. Approach this from the other side... Apart from perhaps taking a little longer, is checking the active path going to be erroneous?

Comment: Just noticed you rolled this back. Without `-F`, `apt-file list` is *very* baggy (and doesn't answer the question at all). Try it with `login` if you want to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Oli Oops, I saw that you added `PACKAGE_NAME` where it didn't belong and hadn't noticed `-F` which was indeed missing. Regarding lightdm, that directory is a bit weird; the commands there aren't things you'd typically used from the command line anyway. I've added another complication to my answer: alternatives. Man, there's just no good way to list that information.

Comment: `dlocate` [works wonderfully](http://askubuntu.com/a/435176/85695) for installed packages, even gets the ones in `/lib` though it doesn't deal with alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

My other answer is fairly certain but only works for installed packages. Here's a crack at a version that works for packages not yet installed (but ones that are only available in the main repositories)

```
export PACKAGE="login"; source /etc/lsb-release; source <(dpkg-architecture); for f in $(wget -qO- "http://packages.ubuntu.com/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/$DEB_BUILD_ARCH/$PACKAGE/filelist" | sed -n '1,/<pre>/d;/<\/pre>/,$d;p'); do [[ $f =~ ^${PATH//:/|} ]] && echo ${f##*/}; done
```

It's horrifically more complicated so I'll write a broken down version:

```
export PACKAGE="login";
source /etc/lsb-release;
source <(dpkg-architecture);

URL="http://packages.ubuntu.com/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/$DEB_BUILD_ARCH/$PACKAGE/filelist"

# We grab the packages.ubuntu.com version of the file list (and strip it with sed)
for f in $(wget -qO- "$URL" | sed -n '1,/<pre>/d;/<\/pre>/,$d;p'); do

    # We then compare every file provided in the package with every path stub
    [[ $f =~ ^${PATH//:/|} ]] && echo ${f##*/};
done
```

Comment: Unless you have very limited bandwidth and are installing from CD, it's simpler to use `apt-file`. And again use hard-coded directories, not the user's `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

An easier method is just querying the web:

```bsh
release=$(lsb_release -sc)
arch=$(uname -m)
package=$@

for i in $package; do
   printf "List of files in $i package"
   curl http://packages.ubuntu.com/$release/$arch/$i/filelist 2>/dev/null | grep -oP '/[\w\d/.]+$
done
```

This has the advantage that you would only need curl and sed (what Ubuntu system doesn't have them) and you can change it with wget easily if necessary. It queries several packages with a single command which is a plus.

---

Any equivalent with other programing language + html parser should work better and less likely to break if something change in the package list.

Changing the host you can also query Debian database.