# How to find all the available commands in a package before installing it?

Tags: command-line

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436278/how-do-i-list-commands-a-package-provides) question clearly explains about how to find all the commands which are provided by a particular installed package.

My question is, how to find(or lists) all the available commands which are provided by a particular package before installing that package via terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`apt-file`**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apt-file/) (is not installed by default in Ubuntu). Before of the first use, run `apt-file update` to fetch contents files from apt-sources.

Here is an example:

```
apt-file -F list geany | egrep -w "(s|)bin"
geany: /usr/bin/geany
```

And an example with a package with more commands:

```
apt-file -F list mesa-utils | egrep -w "(s|)bin"
mesa-utils: /usr/bin/glxdemo
mesa-utils: /usr/bin/glxgears
mesa-utils: /usr/bin/glxheads
mesa-utils: /usr/bin/glxinfo
```

In this case the commands are, evidently: `glxdemo`, `glxgears`, `glxheads` and `glxinfo`.

Comment: `apt-file -F list geany | grep -w bin` displays nothing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I just edited my answer.