# How do I Run/Use apps added from command line?

Tags: software-installation

NEWBIE Alert for sure. But I was in a forum that suggested all these tweaks and adding a few desktop widgets. I followed those and all went well...however, how the heck do I actually get them to run???

Comment: Well, it would be nice if you actually linked the forum you've read or at least mentioned which "tweaks" we're talking about here.

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/436278/how-do-i-list-commands-a-package-provides

Comment: Reboot and then search for the in the Dash.

Comment: For example I sudo blah blah Beancounter, a stock app. all went well. But now how do I get it to run?

Answer (score 0):

check if you can run the apps from command line.
If so , create a shortcut , and edit it. Add the shell command to the shortcut from the properties menu. 
Now , you will have desktop shortcuts for your applications.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your `/usr/share/applications` folder, there may be a Desktop file there. If not, you will have to find out the command-line command. Once you find it, just type this into a text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=App Name
Exec=command
Icon=optional-icon
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;Gnome;Utility;
```

I'm sorry, mobile app doesn't like line breaks. Before each assigned variable, there should be a newline.

and save it as `appname.desktop`